# Interior and Exterior Points in C[0,1] with Supremum Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of real, continuous functions on the set $[0,1]$ with the metric
\begin{equation}
d(f,g)=sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|.
\end{equation}
Consider the set $C$ of constant functions. How would one go about finding the interior, exterior and boundary points of $C$ with this metric?

It seems for any constant value $c$ I have a range of continuous functions from $(c-r,c+r)$ for any radius $r$. However, I can also just as easily consider $r \sin(x) + c$, which is also within a ball of radius $r$ from $c$. It seems to me that there are only boundary points for this set. That is $\partial C = C$. Can anyone provide a proof for this result or otherwise? Are there any interior or exterior points?

Comment: You actually gave a proof: If $\mathring C$ was non-empty, there would exist a constant function $f$ and an open neighborhood $N\subset C$ of $f$. But you can find a non constant function $g$ arbitrarily close to $f$, which is a contradiction. Hence$$C=\partial C\cup \mathring C = \partial C.$$

Answer (score 1):

Τhe interior of $C$ is the empty set: otherwise, there would be a constant function $c$ such that a whole $\epsilon$ ball would contain only constant functions, a contradiction.

The closure of $C$ is $C$: the convergence in this metric is the uniform convergent. So, if a sequence of constant functions converges uniformly (to a continuous function $f$), then $f$ should be constant.

The boundary of $C$ is $\overline{C}\setminus C^{\circ}=C.$